# Compass different css output path and url helpers

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass

I've got a problem with different .css output path (to specific file) in compass project.

Let's say I've got directory tree like this:

```
 /
 ..Fonts
 ..Folder
 ..Images
 ..Sass
   .._mixins.scss
   ..[other_stuff]
 ..Styles
 ..config.rb
```

This is my `config.rb`:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "Styles"
sass_dir = "Sass"
images_dir = "Images"
javascripts_dir = "Scripts"
fonts_dir = "Fonts"

output_style = :nested
relative_assets = true
color_output = false
```

## Goal

I need to use sass inside "Folder" dir, I mean some example.scss file has to be compiled into example.css inside "Folder". But, I have to use compass with relative url helpers and some mixins defined in "Sasss/_mixins.scss" file.

## Problem

The problem is, I can't specify different output path for `example.scss`, because output path for scss is specified in `config.rb` (`Styles`), right? Ok, so I tried adding ruby code to `config.rb` in order to move example.css after it is compiled from "Styles" dir to "Folder" dir like this:

```
require 'fileutils'
on_stylesheet_saved do |file|
  if File.exists?(file) && File.basename(file) == "example.css"
    puts "Moving: #{file}"
    FileUtils.mv(file, File.dirname(file) + "/../Folder/" + File.basename(file))
  end
end
```

BUT, now relative image-url() does not work properly, because it was compiled in "Styles" dir, thus url is relative to this directory not the "Folder" one.

## Solution?

So my question is: what is the best possible way or hack to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only graceful solution is to move your Galleria sub-project into a separate project. You actually have two projects, why are you trying to manage them as one? Instead, keep them separated and put them together during deployment.

Alternatively, create a Compass extension out of the sub-project (if its structure and amount of changes you make in it allow that) and inject necessary stuff into your main project by importing it (directly or via mixins).

One dirty solution is to use symbolic links:

```
cd Styles
ln -s ../Folder Folder
```

And then create `Sass/Folder/foo.sass`.

But this makes `compass compile` go crazy and recreate your whole project every time (rather than overwriting only modified files).

You can also try creating symbolic links in the opposite direction, but you have to make sure your web server [allows](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#Options) [following](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks) symbolic links

Comment: Symbolic links are not an option. Yes, I think the best solution for this is to manage them as two separate projects. Thanks.